# Behaviors Error on GridView Generated Items Data Template in UWP

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I created a custom data template for GridView Generated Items in UWP. Here is screenshot:

[image]

*Here is the XAML Code:*

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="FileExplorer_FolderItem">
        <Grid x:Name="FileExplorer_Item" MaxWidth="0" MaxHeight="0" Margin="0" MinWidth="450" MinHeight="250" RequestedTheme="Dark">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="PathBorder" BorderThickness="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Border.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Jet}"/>
                </Border.BorderBrush>
            </Border>
            <Grid x:Name="Header" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Image x:Name="ThumbnailImage" Source="{Binding Thumb}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="Footer" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF343434"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid x:Name="PathGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Storage_item.DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontSize="15" LineHeight="20"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Path" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Storage_item.Path}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,0,10" FontSize="13" LineHeight="16"/>
                </Grid>
                <Image x:Name="Logo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="48" Grid.Column="1" Source="Images/Folder48.png" Stretch="UniformToFill">



                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

After that, I installed "Behaviors.Managed for UWP by Microsoft" from GitHub for creating some behaviors in my template. I drag&drop "ChangePropertyAction" to image control in my template. However, this error occurred in XAML designer:

**The 'EventTriggerBehavior' does not support direct content.**

*Image of XAML Designer:*

[image]

*And XAML Code of Image control:*

```
 <Image x:Name="Logo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="48" Grid.Column="1" Source="Images/Folder48.png" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerPressed">
                            <Core:ChangePropertyAction/>
                        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

                </Image>
```

I cannot solve why XAML designer gives this error. How can I fix it ?

Thanks for support.

Comment: What is the `ChangePropertyAction` doing in this case?

Comment: @TóthTibor I cannot complete the behavior completely because of error. But I'm planning change the folder icon with video file icon in template if generated item is a storage file and ".mp4" file with the behavior.

Comment: Why behavior is needed in this scenario? Based on your description, why I think using Converter without behavior is more suitable for your case?

Comment: Hi @GraceFeng-MSFT, thanks for suggestion. So far, I've used behaviors in my projects, it's entirely a matter of habit. I'm not predict exactly how I could use Converter in this scenario.

Comment: Noticed that I answered your last question, is that an acceptable answer? Is this case the follow up question of your last one? If so, then your items should be added from code behind, the file icon should be generated when the item is added, not when the user press on the item, right?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Yes, it looks an acceptable answer. Item and item icon will be generated based on StorageFile's file extension when the item is added to View Grid ItemsSource. No click needed, you are right. But, how can I do this via Converter ?

Comment: I wrote an answer below, please, if you find my answer helpful, mark that answer.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, Ok, I will try it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion, and last answer I've delivered, here is a demo to show the usage of `Converter` in this scenario:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ThumbnailToImageConverter x:Key="cvt" />
        <local:MusicTypeConverter x:Key="typecvt" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <GridView x:Name="gridView">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail, Converter={StaticResource cvt}}" Stretch="None" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,5" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding FileType, Converter={StaticResource typecvt}}" Stretch="None" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Model> Collection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var files = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var thumbnail = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 100);

        Collection.Add(new Model { Name = file.Name, Thumbnail = thumbnail, FileType = file.FileType });
    }
    gridView.ItemsSource = Collection;
}
```

Data model:

```cs
public class Model
{
    public StorageItemThumbnail Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string FileType { get; set; }
}
```

The `MusicTypeConverter`:

```cs
public class MusicTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if ((string)value == ".mp4")
                return "Assets/Music.PNG";
        }
        return "Assets/Video.PNG";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For the part of `ThumbnailToImageConverter`, I've posted the code in your last question.

In the new `MusicTypeConverter`, you can add your wanted file type and your icon image path.